# Set JsonPropertyOrder for dynamic field

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I have a POJO `ResponseBuilder` to create Json response for my rest endpoint. Here the item name can be generic depending on the type of item asked in the query. To set this dynamic property name at runtime, I am using `@JsonAnyGetter` as shown below.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ResponseBuilder {

    @JsonIgnore
    private final String type;

    private final List<?> items;

    @Getter
    private final Integer itemCount;

    @Getter
    private final Long totalItems;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, List<?>> getItemsMap() {
        return Collections.singletonMap(type, items);
    }
}
```

Now, I want the `items` list to come at top of the Json response. But I cannot add this in `@JsonPropertyOrder` because property name is decided at runtime. What can I do to achieve this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The JSON fields are unique and without any order - that's the definition of JSON. Why do you want to achieve something like that?

Comment: I want to show pagination related properties like itemCount, totalItems, and page at the bottom of my response.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I want to follow this pattern to show these metadata at bottom like elasticsearch API shows them at top.

Comment: You need to split the responsibilities. The API provides the data, the ElasticSearch processes them and there is a GUI tool (either Kibana or if there is something that can read from the ElasticSearch directly, I don't know) that is responsible for displaying, i. e. the order of the displayed fields should be in the responsibility of the GUI tool. To clarify why I say that, I am not aware Spring supports ordered JSON fields as JSON is by definition unordered.